# FullSimplify returns unevaluated

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
FullSimplify[(veff + 
vF) Coth[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
  veff Abs[x + X2]))/(
vF^2 \[Beta])] Csch[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
  veff Abs[x + X2]))/(vF^2 \[Beta])]^2 HeavisideTheta[
x - X1] Sign[X1], Assumptions -> x + X2 < 0 && x > 0 && x - X1 > 0]
```

Gives

```
 (veff + vF) Coth[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
 veff Abs[x + X2]))/(
 vF^2 \[Beta])] Csch[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
 veff Abs[x + X2]))/(vF^2 \[Beta])]^2 HeavisideTheta[x - X1] 
 Sign[X1]
```

Comment: Seems to stem from this basic design flaw

Comment: In[148]:= FullSimplify[Abs[x], Assumptions -> x < 0]

Out[148]= Abs[x]    Instead of -x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (veff + 
     vF) Coth[(π (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
         veff Abs[x + 
            X2]))/(vF^2 β)] Csch[(π (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
          veff Abs[x + X2]))/(vF^2 β)]^2 HeavisideTheta[x - X1] Sign[
    X1];

expr2 = Assuming[x + X2 < 0 && x > 0 && x - X1 > 0,
  expr // ComplexExpand // Simplify]

(veff + vF) Coth[(π (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) - veff (x + X2)))/(
  vF^2 β)] Csch[(π (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) - veff (x + X2)))/(
  vF^2 β)]^2 Sign[X1]
```

This assumes that all variables are real. If any of the variables are complex, add that to the [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Comment: Although it would be nice if Abs[x] simplified to -x when x < 0 rather than returning Abs[x] as it is ....

Comment: @QuasarSupernova - With v13.2.1 (and probably others) `Assuming[x < 0, Abs[x] // ComplexExpand // Simplify]` evaluates to `-x`

Answer (score 1):

The help file for Abs says: gives the absolute value of the real or complex number z. In your case, x isn't explicitly a real or complex number so Abs[x] returns unevaluated. You may be able to address this limitation using Sign, since

```
 FullSimplify[Sign[x], Assumptions -> x < 0]
```

returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

Only workaround:

```
 f = (veff + 
 vF) Coth[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
   veff*Abs[x + X2]))/(
vF^2 \[Beta])] Csch[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) + 
   veff Abs[x + X2]))/(vF^2 \[Beta])]^2 HeavisideTheta[
x - X1] Sign[X1];

F = f /. Abs[x + X2] -> (x + X2)/Sign[x + X2]

FullSimplify[F, Assumptions -> x + X2 < 0 && x > 0 && x - X1 > 0]

(*(veff + vF) Coth[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) - 
 veff (x + X2)))/(
vF^2 \[Beta])] Csch[(\[Pi] (vF (T1 vF - T2 vF + x - X1) - 
 veff (x + X2)))/(vF^2 \[Beta])]^2 Sign[X1]*)
```

$\text{sgn}(\text{X1}) (\text{veff}+\text{vF}) \coth \left(\frac{\pi  (\text{vF} (\text{T1} \text{vF}-\text{T2} \text{vF}+x-\text{X1})-\text{veff}
   (x+\text{X2}))}{\beta  \text{vF}^2}\right) \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi  (\text{vF} (\text{T1} \text{vF}-\text{T2} \text{vF}+x-\text{X1})-\text{veff}
   (x+\text{X2}))}{\beta  \text{vF}^2}\right)$